# How to work around node.js require caching in coffeescript?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I want to require a file, written in CoffeeScript in another file also written in CoffeeScript. I want want to require that file again when it changes (using `fs.watch()`), however as document module.require caches requires.

Is there an easy way to work around this?

**Update:**

This still doesn't seem to work:

```
fs.watch './file.coffee', (event, filename) ->
  delete require.cache[__dirname + '/' + filename]
  require './file'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invalidate require cache:

> **require.cache#Object**
>
> Modules are cached in this object when they are
>   required. By deleting a key value from this object, the next require
>   will reload the module.

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#require.cache

Comment: Thanks for your help. I now have some code, but it still doesn't seem to work. The event is triggered, however it appears that it gets deleted, but not required again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should do require.cache["mymodule"] = null; then require("mymodule") again, it should be fine.

Comment: while this certainly works as advertised, you still have to be careful in the general case. say your module has a function that returns a list when called, and another module called that function and holds a reference to that list. now when the module gets re-required, that reference is still there, yet another call to the function will return a different result. that may not be a problem in most cases, but general wisdom has it that terminating the entire process and starting a new one is what you do on code changes.